# MySQL query shows die error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following is my test.php page which gets redirected from registration.php page.
everything over here works very fine except sql query. All the alert tags show session variable values perfectly well, but this page gives 'Error, insert query failed' error.
Tried all possibilities like quotes to variables in query, etc., But nothing is working.. Please someone help..

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
session_start();

$ser= $_SESSION['service'];
$comp=$_SESSION['comp'];
$yr= $_SESSION['year'];
$addr= $_SESSION['addr'];
$per= $_SESSION['per'];
$no= $_SESSION['no'];
$email= $_SESSION['email'];
$uname= $_SESSION['uname']; 
  echo "<script>alert('$ser')</script>";
  echo "<script>alert('$comp')</script>";
  echo "<script>alert('$yr')</script>";
  echo "<script>alert('$no')</script>";
  echo "<script>alert('$addr')</script>";
if($ser=='designing'){
   $ser=1;
}else if($ser=='webdev'){
   $ser=2;
}else{
   $ser=3;
}
echo "<script>alert('$ser')</script>";
$sql= "insert into login values 
      ('$uname','xxxx',$ser,'$comp',$yr,'$addr','$per',$no,'$email')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed');
?>

<span style="font-family:Tahoma; font-weight:bold; font-size:11px;color:#666666" 
      align=center>Your Registration is successful...<br/>Our team will contact you at
      the earliest...
</span>
```

Comment: Well, you _might_ want to inspect the output of `mysql_error()`.... Just a thought...

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $sql;` and `echo mysql_error();`?

Comment: replace `die('Error, ...')` with `die('Error: '. mysql_error() )` to get specific details about the error.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions now, but echo mysql_error(); echoes nothing at all & with all this my error page shows this way:: insert into login values ('pra','xxxx',1,'xyz.com',2011,'Hyd','xyz',1234567890,'xyz@xyz.com')Error:mysql_error()

Comment: @user1441956, can you try running the query `insert into login values ('pra','xxxx',1,'xyz.com',2011,'Hyd','xyz',1234567890,'xyz@xyz.com')` in your mysql DB and see whether it's working or not.

Comment: What does your PHP error log say?  What happens when you try to do a very simple MySQL insert from code using the query above?  Try $sql = "insert into login values ('pra','xxxx',1,'xyz.com',2011,'Hyd','xyz',1234567890,'xyz@xyz.com')".  You probably have a permission issue with your DB username.

Answer (score 8):

```
mysql_query() or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed');
yes i too wrote the same but not working

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting formula. However, I would rather recommend something like this:

```
mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_error()) die('Error, insert query failed');
```

If You are interested in why it died, then:

```
mysql_query($sql);
if ($error = mysql_error()) die('Error, insert query failed with:' . $error);
```

But beware, this kind of error shall not be visible for users.

Comment: still not working :( actually im working on this single insert statement since morning in all possible ways  only fault is with sql part, my table is like this:: uname, paswd, service-int, company, year-int, addr, con_per, con_no-int, email   evrything else is varchar

Comment: Does it show an mysql error when executed? Also Are You sure that inserted values are escaped by mysql_real_escape_string() ? http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: No it does not show myql error, & even for a perfect input also, it does not get inserted

Comment: It is totaly weird. It shall throw an error. What about server or DB cache? Is it replicated database? What about PHP error. Is PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: Oooor, do this table have integer ID with autoincrement? You might run out of integer value range. Then MySQL usualy don't report anything but it just doesn't insert new lines. :-)

Comment: I finally did one this, i converted all integer datatypes into varchars & for length of those values & validations i wrote php script in registration page.. finally it worked now.. but for this i changed by database :(

Comment: So it might be problem of integer range? Try use unsigned bigint for datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "insert into login values 
  ('$uname','xxxx',$ser,'$comp',$yr,'$addr','$per',$no,'$email')";
```

Remove the simple quotes from your variables

```
  $sql= "insert into login values 
      ($uname, xxxx, $ser, $comp, $yr, $addr, $per, $no, $email)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "insert into login (field1, field2, ....) values
```

('$uname','xxxx',$ser,'$comp',$yr,'$addr','$per',$no,'$email')";

Also please use BIND and not unfiltered data from user.
Another Also: please use `mysqli_*` instead of old `mysql_*`